# How to build rtabmap_ros with octomap?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, build, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

[This](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=rtabmpa_ros+) guide says that the topics pertaining to octomap like `octomap_full`, `octomap_binary`, etc. are only available with I have `rtabmap_ros` build with `octomap`. How exactly am I supposed to do this? In the documentation of rtabmap_ros I could not find a way to build it from soruce with octomap.

Can anyone help me if I am missing anything?

Thanks and cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404084/how-to-build-rtabmap_ros-with-octomap?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2022-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The binaries are already built with octomap. If you build from source, jsut make sure `ros-$ROS_DISTRO-octomap-ros` is installed, then cmake/catkin will find it.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2022-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2022-07-26**:
Thanks Mathieu!